# How to set Cron job that run after every three hours for indefinite period; with Logging?

Tags: cron

I Want to run Cronjob; after every three hours from last run time for indefinite period and can check whether it ran or not

Could anyone help me in getting what values to be give in this format:

```
crontab -e
```

Tried following:

```
0 0/3 * * * /home/wlogic/SHScripts/DiskCheck/DiskSpaceCheck.sh
```

When I save file using :wq

I get the message:

```
crontab: installing new crontab
"/tmp/crontab.vErqAL":1: bad hour
errors in crontab file, can't install.
Do you want to retry the same edit?
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to use the following line to run a job every 3 hours:

```
0 */3 * * * /home/wlogic/SHScripts/DiskCheck/DiskSpaceCheck.sh
```

To check whether your cron job ran, check your syslog or cron log. This can be different between distributions, for example:

Ubuntu: `/var/log/syslog`

```
Dec  1 11:17:01 testhost CRON[6746]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
```

CentOS: `/var/log/cron`

```
Dec  1 11:01:01 testhost run-parts(/etc/cron.hourly)[13259]: starting 0yum-hourly.cron
Dec  1 11:03:50 server run-parts(/etc/cron.hourly)[13302]: finished 0yum-hourly.cron
```

Solaris: `/var/cron/log`

```
>  CMD: /usr/lib/sa/sa1
>  sys 12394 c Tue Dec  1 11:20:00 2015
<  sys 12394 c Tue Dec  1 11:20:00 2015
```

If you want to log all output of the scheduled command itself you can use the following:

```
0 */3 * * * /home/wlogic/SHScripts/DiskCheck/DiskSpaceCheck.sh > /path/to/job-log 2>&1
```

The above will redirect the output (if any) to the logfile `/path/to/job-log` and will also redirect the output of `STDERR` to this logfile.

Comment: Thanks. This is correct but my question is not answered fully. I mean also asked how to check log whether my script ran or not?

Comment: What this means -> /path/to/job-log 2>&1 ; i put it like /home/wlogic/SHScripts/DiskCheck/logs/job-log 2>&1

Comment: the `> /path/to/job-log` part means to redirect STDOUT (standard output) of the command to a file called `job-log` in directory `/path/to` (substitute with something like `/tmp/DiskSpaceCheck.out`). The `2>&1` part means to redirect the output of STDERR (file descriptor 2) to STDOUT (file descriptor 1).